# Horizontal alignment of two lines of text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to horizontally align the words "if", as depicted in the image below.

[image]

I have tried to use a `minipage` environment, but this did not yield the desired result. The code for this section of text is shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\textit{Case 2}: 
If $s=0$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} 1=N.\] If $s=N$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp (2\pi ir)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} [\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)]=N.\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution in this case is to use an `\hphantom{}`:

```
\hphantom{\textit{Case 2}:}
```

There are two outcomes, depending on if the initial indent was desired or not:

[image]

#### Notes:

- Besides `\hphantom{}` which provides the exact *horizontal* space as its paramter, there is als `\vphantom{}` which provides *only* the vertical spacing (with zero horizontal space).  For this case you could also have just used the `\phatom{}` macro which inserts both the horizontal *and* vertical spacing of its parameter.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textit{Case 2}: 
If $s=0$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} 1=N.\] 
\hphantom{\textit{Case 2}:}
If $s=N$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp (2\pi ir)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} [\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)]=N.\]

\hrule\medskip\par

\textit{Case 2}: 
If $s=0$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} 1=N.\] 

\hphantom{\textit{Case 2}:}
If $s=N$, then 
\[\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp (2\pi ir)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} [\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)]=N.\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This did not appear to work. Are you able to provide the whole code?

Comment: @MB: Yeah, I was working on getting the image to include.

Comment: What a handy command! Thanks for that!

Comment: @MB: Yeah I have used it quite often. I will update the answer to mention the other variants.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean like this?:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{align*}  
\textit{Case 2}:\quad
&\text{If} s=0, \text{then}
\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} 1=N. \\
&\text{If} s=N, \text{then}
\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp (2\pi ir)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} [\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)]=N.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{align*}  
\textit{Case 2}:\quad
&\text{If}\quad s=0, \text{then}\\
&\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} 1=N. \\
&\text{If}\quad s=N, \text{then}\\
&\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp (2\pi ir)=\sum_{r=1}^{N} [\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)]=N.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]